# Sequelize - Aggregate Function Many-to-Many

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a many-to-many relationship with a junction `organizaiton_member` between my `user` and `organization` tables. I am trying to create a query that counts the number of user_id's present where the `organization_id` matches a specific integer. The expected outcome on my end is a single row with the total count of user_ids as one column and the organization_Id as a second column. I thought that I would be able to achieve this with the following query, but I receive an error, `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "user.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Is there a reason why this has to be done? Sorry for the lack of experience working with SQL involving aggregates and many-to-many.

**Query:**

```
models.User.findAll({
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('user.user_id')), 'user_count']],
        include: [{
            model: models.Organization,
            where: {
                organizationId: req.session.organizationId
            },
            attributes: ['organization_id'],
            group: ['organiztion.organization_id']
        }],
    })
```

**User Schema:**

```
user_id
first_name
last_name
email
```

**Organization Schema:**

```
organization_id
org_name
```

**Organization_Member Schema:**

```
user_id
organization_id
```

**SQL Generated:**

```
SELECT "user"."user_id"                                      AS "userId", 
       Count("user"."user_id")                               AS "user_count", 
       "organizations"."organization_id"                     AS 
       "organizations.organizationId", 
       "organizations"."organization_id"                     AS 
       "organizations.organization_id", 
       "organizations.organization_member"."created_at"      AS 
       "organizations.organization_member.created_at", 
       "organizations.organization_member"."updated_at"      AS 
       "organizations.organization_member.updated_at", 
       "organizations.organization_member"."user_id"         AS 
       "organizations.organization_member.user_id", 
       "organizations.organization_member"."organization_id" AS 
       "organizations.organization_member.organization_id" 
FROM   "user" AS "user" 
       INNER JOIN ("organization_member" AS "organizations.organization_member" 
                   INNER JOIN "organization" AS "organizations" 
                           ON "organizations"."organization_id" = 
"organizations.organization_member"."organization_id") 
ON "user"."user_id" = "organizations.organization_member"."user_id" 
AND "organizations"."organization_id" = 1;
```